# Insert a value from one table to another with mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one is books and another is authors.

Books table -

```
id |    name    | auth_id | auth_name
1  |    Book1   |  1      | null
2  |    Book2   |  2      | null
3  |    Book3   |  3      | null
```

Authors table

```
id | firstname | lastname 
1  |    John   |  Stark    
2  |    Jobs   |  Steve     
3  |    Amar   |  Shrama
```

Here auth id refers to the primary key of the Authors table.
Now I want to fill the auth_name column of book table from Authors table.

I am using the following query for this.

```
INSERT INTO `books` (auth_name)
SELECT CONCAT(`lastname`, ',', `firstname`)
FROM `Authors`
Left join `books` on `books`.`auth_id` = `Authors`.`id`;
```

But it's not working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: No need to copy the names, drop that auth_name column from the books table! (a.k.a. Normalization.)

Comment: you don't need auth_name column in Books table. you can get all the data in Authors table using auth_id (foreign key) in Books table. you need to improve your database normalization knowledge.   [database-normalization tutorial](https://www.w3schools.in/dbms/database-normalization/)

Comment: I know Supun Perera. It was not an actual use case. I was just trying to explain my question with an example. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the data not to insert. You can achieve it as below:

```
UPDATE books
INNER JOIN books ON books.auth_id = authers.id
SET books.auth_name = CONCAT(lastname, ',', firstname)
```

If "Authors" tables have all the author id which is in books then it is left join is not needed, if that is not the case then use the left join.

Comment: Ohh yes :). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

use this query

```
UPDATE books 
SET auth_name = (SELECT CONCAT(lastname, ',', firstname) FROM authors WHERE id = auth_id)
```